# I have a gridview in wpf and have a two radio buttons and a button in template column. how do i access the status of radio buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I have a gridview in wpf and have a two radio buttons and a button in template column. How do i access the status of radio buttons in the click event of the button?

```
 <DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TrackingID}" Header="TrackingID" Visibility="Hidden" Width="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserFullName}" Header="Name" Width="140" />                                       
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="350">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Width="50" Content="Yes" GroupName="status" />
                            <RadioButton Width="50" Content="No" GroupName="status" IsChecked="True" />
                            <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click">View Details</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I am capturing the event for the button in Button_Click() function. In this function i want to know which radio button has been selected.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                
                int trackingid = Convert.ToInt32((((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as DataRowView)[0].ToString()); //get the tracking id of the request

                //(((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as RadioButton) //not working

        }
```

Kindly help.

Comment: @Dmitry we are not using MVVM.

Comment: good for you:) then I'd use Binding with ElementName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use binding (in case when your Yes/No is purely a UI property or by whatever reason, you still have an option. Give your RadioButtons names by using x:Name - smth. like "YesRadioButton" and "NoRadiOButton" and then:

Call `FinName("YesRadioButton")` for the shared container (parent of your `RadioButtons`).

or

Use `ElementName` binding, i.e. bind your button's tag to IsChecked of any of your `RadiButtons`

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
 <RadioButton x:Name="YesRadioButton" Width="50" Content="Yes" GroupName="status" />
 <RadioButton x:Name="NoRadioButton" Width="50" Content="No" GroupName="status" IsChecked="True" />
 <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding ElementName='YesRadioButton', Path='IsChecked'}">View Details</Button>   
</StackPanel>
```

then in your button click simply inspect sender's `Tag` property.

Comment: You are right on target ! That's what I was looking for. Never occurred to my mind that we can use ElementName binding. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) everything you need to your item, then cast the `DataContext` of the `Button` (in `sender`) to the item that it is and check which properties are set.

Comment: Are you saying this : (((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as RadioButton ?

Comment: @HotTester: No, `var data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyClass`, the `RadioButton.IsChecked` should be bound to some property of `MyClass`, then you can just get that property.

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler, the sender is the button. So you can look for the parent StackPanel, then search through the children for the RadioButtons, and see which IsChecked is true.

However, this is very fragile based on the exact setup of the UI items.

A better way would be to bind the IsChecked to properties on your model (or whatever you are binding to in the DataGridTextColumns). That way if your view changes, the Click-handler won't need to be adjusted.

Comment: @Dmitry You have something that you are binding to in your DataGridTextColumns.

Comment: True, but it can be an object having no 'UI' properties per se.

Comment: @Dmitry That object is your Model. If you then see that you need some additional properties for view-specific things, you add a layer in between. That layer is called ViewModel.

Comment: @ Daniel Rose Is it? Of course I know that, what I was trying to say to ya is that in absense of a proper VM layer the only choice you have is to pollute your M with UI properties, which you better off not.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, that can happen. The question is then why adding a ViewModel layer isn't done. IMHO it's a (much) better solution than trying to search for named UI items.

Comment: @ Daniel Rose - it probably is, but the app in the sample is heavily data centric, based on the published snippet of c# code:) there must be a reason for that. Besides - biting your own elbow (aka MVVM) is NOT a fun for everyone.